Publish Failure Reporting Add or Build Definition File
Unable to publish a buildable and working .Net-based Logic App in VSCode. Am I missing a build definition in my project?
Why is this happening and how to resolve?

To publish, I should use the up arrow to publish to my Subscription/Tenant, but it shows Add Build Definition to Project instead.

When I click the button, I see a failed error message of {} instead of anything insightful.

Even the report of an issue fails to know its context and sends me to a 404 page.


The add build definition also reports the same failure {} after a new Azure: Create Logic App.

What style are you building?  Consumption or Standard because you seem to have mixed both types.

@ΩmegaMan I believe you don't need to publish it as its already created in your resource group. After making changes to the logicapp.json file, you need to save it. Once you save it you will get an option to upload it which will update your logic app definition in your subscription

The style is consumption, but I can switch to another. I thought consumption was just a payment tier. @Skin

You need to be clear on what which type of LogicApp you’re developing. It can get very expensive for you very quickly and they are very different underlying architectures.

There are two types of extensions available in vs code for logic app development locally: 1. Consumption logic app extension 2. Standard logic app extension
You don't need to publish it explicitly to Azure portal as while creating the Consumption logic app using the vs code extension, it will ask you to select the subscription and the resource group where it will get created. Hence, it will directly get created in Azure portal. You can visualize it in the portal.
If you are making any changes to the logicapp.json file then save it. Once done, you will prompted to upload the changes to your Azure subscription.

In order to publish the logic app explicitly to Azure portal, you need to install Standard logic app extension and create a logic app workspace. You can publish it as shown below once you are done with the development.

References-
Quickstart - Create integration workflows with Azure Logic Apps in Visual Studio Code - Azure Logic Apps | Microsoft Learn.

In the Azure Tab -> Logic Apps (Consumption), there are two logic apps in the cloud. I can edit both XXXX.logicapp.json files (which have the default properties and values), but they are not in either of the two projects I have created for them, so they are not directly linked. What am I missing to have either of my local logic apps be associated with what I have in the cloud, or do new ones need to be created in the cloud? What is the step I am missing? I will review the link you sent to see if I can divine what step I have blown by.

@ΩmegaMan you can visualize both the logic apps as you must be creating the logic apps by selecting the azure subscription, resource group and then location. That means its getting created in azure portal for Consumption extension. I have created a consumption logic app using vs code and I can see the same in Azure portal also. In case of Standard logic app extension you need to explicitly publish it to azure

Two things. 1)  I get what you are saying, but is there no way to build a logic app locally and then get it to or create a new logic app in the cloud based on what is built locally? Is that what you are implying?

In VSCode when I select an existing logic app listed and select Open In Designer  I am not presented, in the designer, with the ability to add triggers or events.  Does one need to 1st add a trigger to the json, save, then select "Open in Designer" to see actions et all in the designer?


I am basing #1 above on this video where he publishes into the cloud. 19. Deploy Logic app Project from VSCode | Logic apps deployment with vscode - YouTube

@ΩmegaMan in the given video he is using standard logic app extension but in Op you are using consumption logic app extension. Debugging, local development comes in for standard logic app extension whereas in consumption logic app extension it will create the logic app directly in azure portal. There are two types of extension available in vs code 1. Consumption logic app extension 2. Standard logic app extension.

Having both extensions, I disabled the consumption and restarted VSCode. In VSCode Azure section it no longer showed the Logic app Consumption task. So I 1) Setup a Workspace in the Azure tab and 2) Clicked on Azure Logic Apps in Workspace and selected Deploy to Logic app which created a standard logic app in the cloud. I then reenabled the consumption extention which brought back the consumption section. Ugggg. Update your answer and I will mark it as resolved. Thx

@ΩmegaMan updated my answer, please check
